# take screen shot of a transparent image android

Tags: android, screenshot

I have a main layout and  a Linear Layout llSplitPic on which a transparent image is set as background. When I'm trying to capture the screenshot threw the code below it returns only the transparent image but I want main layout image because I'm using llSplitView as a frame .

```
llSplitPic.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
llSplitPic.buildDrawingCache();
llSplitPic.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
Bitmap bmp = llSplitPic.getDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method-

```
Bitmap file = takeSnapshot(ParentLayout);

   Bitmap takeSnapshot(View v)
    {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: it gives the screen shot of view but i have a transparent view and wanting that if i take screen shot of transparent part than background image should be captured  that is in background of transparent image

Comment: You must have that view inside some layout. is It?

Comment: yes that views are in same layout
structure is like that
<RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout/><LinearLayout/></RelativeLayout>

Comment: then setid to your parent layout(which is your RelativeLayout),take reference of that layout in java code. and pass the object of that relative layout object in this method

Comment: don't want to take full screen's screen shot

Comment: just want the snap shot of second linear layout

Comment: then do the same for Linear layout or else make another layout layer for your linear layout.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34134/discussion-between-tarun-varshney-and-anddevmanu)